# Restricting a Rails 2.3 Named Route to POST/GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

This is hopefully very easy to do, but I can't find any doco on it anywhere (probably because I am lacking the proper search terms). Anyway...

I want to have two named routes sharing the same path. The distinguishing feature between the two will be that one will accept GETs and the other will accept POSTs.

Below is what I have so far. I have tried to use a :method arg and a :via param, but neither do the trick. I have also tried ":requirements => {:method => :get}".

```
map.show_current '/rounds/', :controller => :rounds, :action => :show, :method => :get
map.create '/rounds/', :controller => :rounds, :action => :create, :via => [:post, :put]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, even just an appropriate search term.

Cheers.

Comment: I think that the :conditions option might do the trick...

Comment: Well, as often has it I have worked it out soon after posting this question.

The option I was looking for was the :conditions option. So my routes now look like this:

    map.show_current '/rounds/', :controller => :rounds, :action => :show, :conditions => { :method => :get }
    map.create '/rounds/', :controller => :rounds, :action => :create :conditions => { :method => :post }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied this from my comment after seeing that my question does not have an answer.

The option I was looking for was the :conditions option. So my routes now look like this:

```
map.show_current '/rounds/', :controller => :rounds, :action => :show, :conditions => { :method => :get }
map.create '/rounds/', :controller => :rounds, :action => :create :conditions => { :method => :post }
```